# Using eslint-plugin-import in a monorepo not reporting errors when it should?

Tags: eslint, monorepo, eslint-plugin-import

If I have the following monorepo set up

- packages/app1 has `is-even` in it's package.json
- packages/app2 does not have `is-even` in its package.json
- packages/app2 tries to use `is-even`

Then currently, I don't get any warning from something like eslint-plugin-import, when preferably, I would like an error because if I publish app2, then any user that tries to install it from NPM will receive errors because it does not properly specify that it needs `is-even` as a dependency

Reproducible case here with a minimal monorepo https://github.com/cmdcolin/yarn_workspaces_eslint_plugin_import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by adding

```
extends:
  - eslint:recommended
  - plugin:import/recommended
rules:
  import/no-extraneous-dependencies: error
```

This makes it detect the error properly, e.g. this message is expected and good now

```
yarn run v1.22.15
$ eslint .

/home/cdiesh/test/packages/app2/src/index.js
  1:1  error  'is-even' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S is-even' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

Comment: thanks to @ljharb on github for this assistance https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2247